# set user password using c# in Active Directory fails

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory

I try to set the user password like this:

```
 user.Invoke("SetPassword", password);
```

But I get an exception

> The server is unwilling to process the request. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072035)
>
> 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A129B, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data
>   0

Sounds familiar to someone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

52D is the error code and thanks to the LDAP Wiki page, the problem was the password complexity restriction -> solution: a stronger password.

[LDAP Wiki](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/WILL_NOT_PERFORM)

Comment: link offline. I hope this helps https://ldap.com/ldap-result-code-reference/

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the link